# MySQL: unexpected behaviour 'in boolean mode'

Tags: mysql, boolean, match

I use the following call for getting information from a database:

```
select * 
from submissions 
where 
   match( description ) against ('+snowboard' in boolean mode ) 
   and (!disabled or disabled='n') 
order by datelisted desc limit 30
```

Which means everything with ‘snowboard' in the description is found. Now here’s the problem:

```
select *
from submissions 
where 
  match( description ) against ('+snowboard +mp4' in boolean mode ) 
  and (!disabled or disabled='n') 
order by datelisted desc limit 30
```

will ignore the +mp4 for some reason and return the same as the first query

```
select * 
from submissions 
where 
   match( description ) against ('+mp4' in boolean mode )
```

doesn't return anything, so basically it appears it's ignored in the search

Does anybody know how to work around this behavior?

Comment: are you sure that anything in submissions has mp4 in the description?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mysql's boolean mode will only match words which are longer than a certain length. and `mp4` is too short. you'd have to recompile mysql to change the threshold

EDIT: turns out, this can now be set via the config file, see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html for furhter reference

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the minimum word length, which by default is 3 characters.
Try the same with `+snowboard +scooter` and you will see that it works. (Supposing you don't have scooters in your database, of course).

See [**Fine-Tuning MySQL Full-Text Search**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html) on how to change it:

> The minimum and maximum lengths of words to be indexed are defined by the `ft_min_word_len` and `ft_max_word_len` system variables. (See Section 5.1.4, “Server System Variables”.) The default minimum value is four characters; the default maximum is version dependent. If you change either value, you must rebuild your FULLTEXT indexes. For example, if you want three-character words to be searchable, you can set the ft_min_word_len variable by putting the following lines in an option file:
>
> `[mysqld]
>   ft_min_word_len=3`
>
> Then restart the server and rebuild your FULLTEXT indexes. Note particularly the remarks regarding myisamchk in the instructions following this list.

Comment: The default minimum word length is 4 characters. http://stackoverflow.com/a/9964377/1487413. You can see this by running this query: `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'ft_min_word_len'`