# mysql full-text search not working for 3 characters

Tags: php, mysql, database, full-text-search

In my website I have implemented search feature using full-text search.

It works fine usually but not sometimes like it gives results when I search with keyword "ship" but not "shi"

But it should return. Please help me why this happening.

Comment: And how exactly have you implemented it? If you want us to spot the bug, you should show us the code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The minimum and maximum lengths of words to be indexed are defined by the `ft_min_word_len` and `ft_max_word_len` system variables. The default minimum value is **4** characters. That is why it's not working with **3** characters.

You need to change its value, and rebuild your `FULLTEXT` indexes. If you want three-character words to be searchable, you can set the `ft_min_word_len` variable by changing its value in the configuration file. Or, if you have super user permissions you can set this environment variable with:

```
  SET  ft_min_word_len=3
```

Get more details here: [**Fine-Tuning MySQL Full-Text Search**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html)